# Why can't cavity length be minimized to spread the spacing between allowed frequencies in a laser cavity?

Tags: laser, laser-cavity

I came to conclusion that it is because by doing so the threshold gain for lasing increases but I'm not completely sure of that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That can, and is, done.  Since the gain curve is narrower than the mode line spacing, only one longitudinal mode lases, creating a "single frequency" laser, or single mode laser.  A pesky consequence is that sometimes the cavity modes straddle the gain curve, meaning there is no output.  Also, small temperature changes cause the cavity length to vary which causes the intensity and frequency to vary with temperature.   To be practical as a "single-frequency" laser the length of the cavity must be stabilized.  Sometimes the cavity length is kept constant by using Invar bars to define the length.  Active cavity control can be implemented by mounting one of the cavity mirrors on a piezo-electric mount, and implementing a control system to keep the cavity mode at the peak of the gain curve.  In gas lasers, the peak of the gain curve can be conveniently located by detection of the Bennett-Lamb dip.  Unfortunately and surprisingly, I can't find a good web presentation of the Bennett-Lamb dip.  Maybe someone else can find one.    There are, of course, other schemes, many of which are mentioned [here, in a text-only (graphics-free) presentation](http://repairfaq.cis.upenn.edu/sam/laserhsl.htm).

Comment: Thanks for answering but I'm not a physics student. I need a very simplier explanation. I know this is not formal but what I'd like to know is: by reducing the cavity length does the gain curve lower or does the lasing threshold increases. Or am I saying the same thing with different words?